# Spinner: How to reduce size of spinner

Tags: android

When I am reducing layout_width and layout_height of spinner the item name gets cut. I want to decrease the size of the spinner without affecting the item names.How to do it?

Comment: Are you using a seperate layout for spinner item?

Comment: no in .xml file there are 3 textviews and 3edittext and one spinner is also there and i want that the spinner should align with them but its too big to fit.

Comment: Decrease the `fontSize` of the Spinner item Text.If this works tell me,i will post it as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Creating Adapter for your Spinner give custom layout instead of predefined one

Create xml named spinner_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:id="@+id/cust_view"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp" 
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

Here you can change the color Text size and width and height of the Elements in the spinner by modifying this textview

Use it like this while creating Adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_row,yourlist);
```

The Last task is routine

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: text size should be in sp